# How to check if some user have selected an item that the other user is about to?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Lets say the quantity of item XYZ is "5". And a user have selected "3" of it. Now if another user goes to the same page and is about to select the item, he should be shown "2" as quantity. If the one of thte user changes the quantity, the quantity shown to other user should change too. But if the first user closes browser tab or cancels the order, the quantity should be changed to "5" for the second user. How can I achieve this using JavaScript, Ajax, Jquery and PHP?

Comment: Its much easier to let both view 5 and when trying to submit the order, let the second one know that there are less available now if the amount he asks goes over the new remaining amount

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled for solutions? Any specific code you need help with? This question is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: Ticketingsystems (for cinemas for example) only show the selection to one user and just for a limited amount of time. This is the easiest and best solution

Comment: what you want to do would be quite complex to get 100% accurate at all times - but doable if you want to invest the time to get it right and learn the technologies required for such realtime gymnastics

Comment: What do you want to do, if two users select everything at the same time?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I realize it is too broad, but I was thinking that there might be a standard solution to this problem, I am looking for something like most Flight/Hotel booking sites have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to create this functionality using PHP and Jquery then this scenario will happen.

1. First of all you need to define one variable in a some table which stored remaining quantity of that product.
2. then when first user enter any amount of quantity for that product you need to call Ajax function and minus that quantity from remaining quantity variable.
3. Now, when second user will open that product page then display that remaining field value. and If second user will add some quantity then again remove that quantity from remaining quantity field.
4. So Every time you have to display product quantity value from that remaining quantity value to user.
5. Every time User will refresh a page, show him latest value of remaining quantity field.
6. To avoid every time refresh a page, You have to call Ajax function into some time interval like in 5 or 10 second. So every 5 second Ajax function will call and fetch the latest remaining quantity value from database and will replace into view.

By this way you can achieve your goal using PHP and Ajax.

There is a another option available like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?utm_campaign=Firebase_announcement_adoption_general_en_05-18-16_&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=ads&gclid=Cj0KEQjwi_W9BRD_3uio_Jz-p8UBEiQANU80vuDpNX7zdJ3ISftrl46WENDYXSK6utjVpFfZpwg0zSAaAjDX8P8HAQ) which will do the same thing without any ajax or API call or page refreshment.